# How to wait until translation array loop complete - with subscribe

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

This is my translation method. getting empty array on console. how to handle this?

```
 headersTranslator(headers) {
    const transHeader: any[] = [];
    headers.map((header) => {
        this.translate.get(header.title).subscribe((value) => {
            if (!value) return;
            transHeader.push({ ...header, title: value });
        });
    });
    console.log('transHeader', transHeader);
    return transHeader;
}
```

my try: **finding challenging because of observable placed under the loop.**

```
 headersTranslator(headers) {
    const transHeader: any[] = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        headers.map((header) => {
            this.translate.get(header.title).subscribe({
                next: (value) =>
                    transHeader.push({ ...header, title: value }),
            });
        });
        resolve(transHeader);
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Comment: @R.Richards - can you check my update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some operator like `forkJoin` to convert an array of observables to a single observable that returns an array of results of those underlying observables

For async version use `firstValueFrom` or `lastValueFrom`:

```
async function headersTranslator(headers) {
    const observables = headers.map(header =>
                                    this.translate.get(header.title)
                                    .pipe(map(value => ({ ...header, title: value }))));
    return await lastValueFrom(forkJoin(observables));       
}
```

Or if you want the function to return the observable and subscribe to it:

```
function headersTranslator(headers) {
    const observables = headers.map(header =>
                                    this.translate.get(header.title)
                                    .pipe(map(value => ({ ...header, title: value }))));
    return forkJoin(observables);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, it works.

```
async headersTranslator(headers) {
    const transHeader: any[] = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        headers.map((header, i) => {
            this.translate
                .get(header.title)
                .subscribe({
                    next: (value) =>
                        transHeader.push({ ...header, title: value }),
                })
                .add(() => {
                    if (headers.length === i + 1) {
                        resolve(transHeader);
                    }
                });
        });
    });
}
```

But looking for a standard way to get it.